# where is `parent` in gtk3?

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk3

I'm sorry to place such a simple question, I'm moving from PyGTK to PyGI, and my program has several labels that are made sensitive to mouse click, by adding them in an `EventBox`; the structure is defined in glade files, and the callbacks are set in the Python code.

In PyGTK, we rely upon being able to find the `EventBox` by reading the `parent` property of the `Label`.

Now I have this simple Python code:

```
if True:
    import gi
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
    from gi.repository import Gtk
else:
    import gtk as Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.eventbox = Gtk.EventBox()
        self.add(self.eventbox)
        self.label = Gtk.Label("click me")
        self.eventbox.add(self.label)
        print self.label.parent

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

which doesn't do anything, runs for PyGtk, but complains with PyGI, saying that `'Label' object has no attribute 'parent'`.

This is not the only place where my code uses the `parent` field, so I need a generic solution.

A working link to `pygi-convert.sh` would provide material for study.

---

in case you wonder, the target software is a [botanic database manager](https://github.com/Ghini/ghini.desktop/).

Comment: You should never, ever implement a "I can't load Gtk-3.0 through introspection, so I'll fall back to pygtk" import; the API between GTK 2.x and 3.x has changed and even if you stick to the strict subset of shared symbols there's no guarantee that a symbol behaves in the same way between major API versions. Either support GTK 2.x or GTK 3.x.

Comment: Hi, sorry to get you confused. the idea was simply to have some code which worked for Gtk2 and ask how do I get it working with Gtk3? … there is no falling back to 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [`get_parent()`](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.get_parent) method:

```
print(self.label.get_parent())
```

Comment: I knew it was something simple. do you by any chance know where to find that `pygi-convert.sh` script, mentioned in several places, but where is it?

Comment: @mariotomo is this what you are looking for? https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/pygobject/raw/master/tools/pygi-convert.sh

Comment: I accepted your answer because you immediately mentioned the correct link, and I'm bookmarking it. thank you.

Comment: @mariotomo You should accept the best answer, not the first one :)

Comment: @JoséFonte interestingly enough, it does not mention `parent`.

Comment: Yes, i wonder. Anyway, many properties present in PyGtk will be available in PyGObject via setters/getters.

Answer (score 1):

You must use the getter method from Gtk.Widget [get_parent()](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#Gtk-3.0/classes/Widget.html#Gtk.Widget.get_parent).

```
if True:
    import gi
    gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
    from gi.repository import Gtk
else:
    import gtk as Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()

        self.eventbox = Gtk.EventBox()
        self.add(self.eventbox)
        self.label = Gtk.Label("click me")
        self.eventbox.add(self.label)
        print self.label.get_parent()

win = MyWindow()
win.connect("destroy", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

After execution:

```
<Gtk.EventBox object at 0x7f802a597910 (GtkEventBox at 0x55a88239a130)>
```